# ¿Cómo puedo crear un plugin de pagos en virtuemart/joomla?

Tags: php, plugin, joomla3

Necesito crear un plugin de joomla 3 + virtuemart 3 integración de pagos con alignet me gustaria saber como iniciar el desarrollo

Answer (score 0):

El proceso inicia revisando la documentación de Virtuemart en cuanto a desarrollo de plugins:

https://docs.virtuemart.net/tutorials/development.html

También hay foros de Virtuemart donde pueden resolver este tipo de preguntas genéricas.

Por último, puedes revisar un plugin existente de Virtuemart y tomarlo como base para crear el tuyo, según la documentación que te da la pasarela de pago.

Comment: amigo gracias por la info talvez no sabes algun sitio donde exista la misma documentacion en español

Comment: Hay un grupo en Facebook de Virtuemart, ahí te pueden colaborar, búscalo "Virtuemart Español"